# Why is my font rendering slowly

Tags: html, css, font-face

I downloaded a font kit from font squirrel called DestroyRegular and I'm using font-face in my css.  The initial rendering of the font seems much slower than it should be.  You can see [my site here](http://pelicanvolleyball.com/).  Can anyone give me advice on how to speed up the rendering of my font, or do I just need a new font altogether?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It will be slow because the fonts are downloaded and then rendered, hence, the more fonts you use, the more requests it will make, thus making your initial loading slow unless and until the fonts are cached by the browser.

If you use [`Google Web Fonts`](http://www.google.com/fonts/), they will show you a page load bar, more the fonts, more the requests, more time for initial loading.

[image]

> You can also turn on Browser Leverage Caching to set expiration
>   headers which will drastically cut down `http` requests for you